# matplotlib histogram with two bars and string values in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dictionary like this:

> {"hi" : {"spam": 3, "ham": 1} , "go": {"spam":2, "ham":4"}}

and I want to plot a histogram which "spam" and "ham" are in x-axel and each of them has two columns with "spam" and "ham" labels.
My problem is how to plot such a histogram.
For multiple columns, I saw this [link](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/histogram_multihist.html), But I didn't figure out how to put strings in the x-axis.
And when I put a string in x-axis I can't make it two column histogram.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking and what you want. Please add more details. How should the final plot look like?

Answer (score 0):

I understandd that this graph I'm trying to plot is not a histogram, so I should plot it with another method like `dataframe.plot()`.